# How should I do a RedisDict in python?

Tags: python, redis, wsgi

I am doing [a really simple API](https://github.com/spiral-project/respire/tree/master/respire/tests/todo) to test respire a SPORE client generation for python.

In WSGI, what would be the best way to keep data throught the server?

I try to make a RedisDict that way:

```
import json
from redis import Redis
redis = Redis()

class RedisDict:
    """A redis based dict."""

    def dict(self):
        TODOS = redis.get('TODOS')
        return json.loads(TODOS)

    def keys(self):
        return self.dict().keys()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.dict()[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        obj = self.dict()
        obj[key] = value
        redis.set('TODOS', json.dumps(obj))

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        obj = self.dict()
        del obj[key]
        redis.set('TODOS', json.dumps(obj))

todos = RedisDict()
```

How can I make `dict(todos)` to return a dict?
Is that enough in a WSGI environment ?

Comment: What is "TODOS" stored as within Redis? A hash?

Comment: Yet it should be an HASH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that method `dict` returns a dictionary, why not just do this:

```
dict_i_wanted = todos.dict()
```

If you must support `dict_i_wanted = dict(todos)` then add this method:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self.dict().iteritems()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your own "`dict-`like" class, you need to implement the dictionary protocol. The easiest way would be inheriting from [`collections.Mapping`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) and implementing the methods that the table mentions are abstract. You need to implement those to behave the same as the corresponding `dict` methods; e.g. `__iter__` should return an iterable over all `(key, value)` tuples. (This is the one method you need to make `dict(todos)` work. There is no magic method to coerce to a `dict` like you tried to do with your `dict()` method.)